# Настройка maven

Tags: maven, java, intellij-idea

В Intellij IDEA пытаюсь сконфигурировать сборку так, чтобы простой класс java в проекте выводил результат на консоль. Сборка происходит, но, кроме результата успешной сборки, ничего не выводит в консоль. Что пошло не так?
 Гуглил, ничего полезного не нашёл, может, кто подскажет?

Comment: Каким образом Вы запускали собранный проект? Что получилось в результате сборки - jar-файл?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал смотреть не в сторону maven, а в сторону gradle. http://gradle.org

Answer (score 1):

Что касается IDEA, можно настроить себе Run Configuration. Можно просто из контекстного меню, когда курсор находится на названии класса, выбрать Run. Насчет maven не уверен, возможно, там есть goal, который запускает выбранный класс, но я maven не пользуюсь, поэтому ищите информацию.

Comment: Оказывается, я просто забыл поставить в Мейн методе (String [] args)... 2 дня сидел, не мог понять, думал в конфигурациях проблема... офигеть х_х
Всем спасибо, тема закрыта))